# What is the relationship between imsmanifest.xml items and the extracted directories?

Tags: xml, moodle, scorm

I have a Moodle common course cartridge export. I've unzipped it.

I have the imsmanifest.xml which has an item element for each HTML page.

For example . . .

```
<item identifier="I_76B26C3C">
        <title></title>
        <item identifier="I_7D49B95A" identifierref="I_9C1CCE4A_R">
          <title>Assignment #3 Answer Key--Ethical Issues Discussion</title>
        </item>
      </item>
      <item identifier="I_062D4F9F" identifierref="I_96B39A78_R">
        <title>Assignment #4: Book Club/Film Discussion</title>
      </item>
```

I expected the identifier or identifierref to match the directory containing the HTML page with the appropriate title but can't figure out any connection. The HTML pages themselves are named in a human readable format but some of the names are the same.

The directories are named `i_ec478774`, `i_f70c6315`, etc. but they don't match anything in the XML file and I can't figure any sort of pattern to tie them back to the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `identifierref` in `<item>` corresponds to an ID in `<resources>`

```
<organizations default="my_org_id">
   <organization identifier="my_org_id">
      <title>Course Title Here</title>
      <item identifier="my_item_1_id" identifierref="my_item_1_resource_id">
         <title>My Activity Title</title>
      </item>
   </organization>
</organizations>
<resources>
   <resource identifier="my_item_1_resource_id" adlcp:scormType="sco" href="myfile.html" type="webcontent">
      <file href="myfile.html"/>
   </resource>
</resources>
```

The `<resource>` node contains the URL for the HTML file.

Depending on how your XML file is configured, it's possible the `<resource>` nodes were split out into a separate file.